# Get Number of active service instances?

Tags: web-services, wcf, performance

Is there anyway of getting the number of active instance of the service I've tried adding a static int counter in the constructor and this works and implemented Idisposable to decrement the counter on the service but the dispose method only gets called when the service host closes?

Is there any native object i can get and see the current instance count?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: why would you ever need that?

Comment: need it to check instancing counts and performance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check out a gazillion of **performance counters** available for WCF:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx
- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aszego/wcf-performance-counters)
- http://www.sajay.com/post/2009/09/13/WCF-Performance-Counters.aspx
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200207095351/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/BVeldhoen/archive/2008/01/26/wcf-latency-test-harness.aspx)

or google or bing for "WCF performance counters" - lots of hits.

Also, with Server 2008 R2 "AppFabric" (f.k.a. "Dublin"), Microsoft promises to bring us a really nice dashboard-style WCF management system - should be out in a few months at the very latest: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/app-main.aspx